# SharePoint in Office 365 permissions with sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, office-365

I have a new tenancy, without any modifications, and I am trying to edit the site collection with sharepoint designer, but I am getting an error that I don't have permissions. I am the tenancy admin for this Office 365. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a normal case in SharePoint inside Office 365. If you have a new tenancy and you can't edit the root site collection in SharePoint designer, that's because editing that root site collection is disabled by default.

You should go to SharePoint's admin center, click on settings,  and in the section for custom scripts, you should enable the scripts for the self-service created sites.

This is considered as a security feature in SharePoint when it comes to Office 365.

Answer (score 1):

Check that SharePoint Designer is enabled.  Under the Site Setting ==> Under Site Collection Administration ==> SharePoint Designer Setting: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this.  Steps I followed (pulled from multiple sites, including here):

- Install harePoint 2013 Designer
- Install SharePoint 2013 Designer SP1
- Ensure SharePoint 2013 Designer is enabled in SharePoint admin
- Ensure custom scripts are allowed in O365 SharePoint Admin Center
- Add SharePoint site to IE Trusted Sites on machine used for editing

I needed all of the above complete / in-place before I could open my O365 site in Designer 2013.